# How do I replace an image of an SKSpriteNode for the duration of an action then return it to it's original texture atlas loop

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios9, texture-atlas

I am trying to make a basic run and jump game in SpriteKit.

When the view loads I wish for the sprite node to `Run` using images from a texture atlas. This I have managed to do.

When the screen is touched I wish this image to change to another image in the texture atlas called `Jump`.

When the character returns to the ground I wish it to go back to the original texture atlas loop.

So far I have coded the following:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class Level1: SKScene {
    var Hero : SKSpriteNode!
    //Creates an object for the Hero character.

    let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named:"RunImages.atlas")
    //Specifies the image atlas used.

    var spriteArray = Array<SKTexture>();
    //Creates a variable for the image atlas of him running.

    var HeroBaseLine = CGFloat (0)
    //This is where the Hero character sits on top of the ground.

    var onGround = true
    //Creates a variable to specify if Hero is on the ground.

    var velocityY = CGFloat (0)
    //Creates a variable to hold a three decimal point specification for velocity in the Y axis.

    let gravity = CGFloat (0.6)
    //Creates a non variable setting for gravity in the scene.

    let movingGround = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "Ground")
    //Creates an object for the moving ground and assigns the Ground image to it.

    var originalMovingGroundPositionX = CGFloat (0)
    //Sets a variable for the original ground position before it starts to move.

    var MaxGroundX = CGFloat (0)
    //Sets a variable for the maximum

    var groundSpeed = 4
    //Sets the ground speed.  This number is how many pixels it will move the ground to the left every frame.

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //Misc setup tasks.

        backgroundColor = (UIColor.blackColor())
        //Sets the background colour when the view loads.

        //Ground related tasks.

        self.movingGround.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
        //Positions the Ground image hard left in the X axis.

        self.movingGround.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + (self.movingGround.size.height / 2))
        //Positions the Ground image at the bottom of the screen relative to half the height of the image.

        self.addChild(self.movingGround)
        //Creates an instance of the Ground image that follows the parameters set in the lines above when the view loads.

        self.originalMovingGroundPositionX = self.movingGround.position.x
        //Sets the starting position for the ground image in the x before it start to move.

        self.MaxGroundX = self.movingGround.size.width - self.frame.size.width
        //Sets the maximum ground size minus the width of the screen to create the loop point in the image.

        self.MaxGroundX *= -1
        //This multiplies the size of the ground by itself and makes the max ground size a negative number as the image is moving towards the left in x which is negative.

        //Hero related tasks.

        spriteArray.append(textureAtlas.textureNamed("Run1"));
        spriteArray.append(textureAtlas.textureNamed("Run2"));
        spriteArray.append(textureAtlas.textureNamed("Run3"));
        spriteArray.append(textureAtlas.textureNamed("Run2"));

        Hero = SKSpriteNode(texture:spriteArray[0]);

        self.HeroBaseLine = self.movingGround.position.y + (self.movingGround.size.height / 2) + 25

        //self.Hero.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 50, self.HeroBaseLine)

        self.Hero.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 50, self.HeroBaseLine)
        //Sets where the character will appear exactly.

        self.Hero.xScale = 0.15
        self.Hero.yScale = 0.15

        addChild(self.Hero);
        //Adds an instance of Hero to the screen.

        let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(self.spriteArray, timePerFrame: 0.15);
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0), duration: 0.0);
        //Although currently set to 0, the above line controls the displacement of the character in the x and y axis if required.
        let group = SKAction.group([ animateAction,moveAction]);
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(group);
        self.Hero.runAction(repeatAction);
        //Animation action to make him run.  Here we can affect the frames and x, y movement, etc.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if self.onGround {
            self.velocityY = -18
            self.onGround = false
        }
    }
    //This block specifies what happens when the screen is touched.

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if self.velocityY < -9.0 {
            self.velocityY = -9.0
        }
    }
    //This block prevents Hero from jumping whilst already jumping.

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

        if self.movingGround.position.x <= MaxGroundX {
            self.movingGround.position.x = self.originalMovingGroundPositionX
        }
        //This is how the ground is positioned at the beginning of each update (each frame refresh)

        movingGround.position.x -= CGFloat (self.groundSpeed)
        //This is how the ground is moved relative to the ground speed variable set at the top.  The number in the variable is how many pixels the frame is being moved each frame refresh.

        self.velocityY += self.gravity
        self.Hero.position.y -= velocityY

        if self.Hero.position.y < self.HeroBaseLine {
            self.Hero.position.y = self.HeroBaseLine
            velocityY = 0.0
            self.onGround = true
        }
        //This is the code for making Hero jump in accordance to the velocity and gravity specified at the top of the class in relation to the base line.
    }
}
```

I have tried to add code in the `touchesBegan` section to change the image texture of the sprite node to another image in my image atlas called `Jump`.

I then wish for the texture atlas to return to animating once the touches ended action is called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I have implemented what you have suggested but it still doesn't work quite correclty.  The hero is changing to the jumping image but does not actually jump and is stuck in the jump image.

I created a JumpImages.atlas and added "Jump" image to that folder.

I have modified the code to the following:

import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class Level1: SKScene {

```
//Creates an object for the Hero character.    

var Hero : SKSpriteNode!

//Specifies the image atlas used.

let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named:"RunImages.atlas")

//Creates a variable for the image atlas of him running.

var spriteArray = Array<SKTexture>();




var jumpArray = Array<SKTexture>();

let jumpAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named:"JumpImages.atlas")

//jumpArray.append(jumpAtlas.textureNamed("Jump"))  Didn't work in this area, moved it to the did move to view.




//This is where the Hero character sits on top of the ground.

var HeroBaseLine = CGFloat (0)

//Creates a variable to specify if Hero is on the ground.

var onGround = true

//Creates a variable to hold a three decimal point specification for velocity in the Y axis.

var velocityY = CGFloat (0)

//Creates a non variable setting for gravity in the scene.

let gravity = CGFloat (0.6)




//Creates an object for the moving ground and assigns the Ground image to it.    

let movingGround = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "Ground")

//Sets a variable for the original ground position before it starts to move.

var originalMovingGroundPositionX = CGFloat (0)

//Sets a variable for the maximum

var MaxGroundX = CGFloat (0)

//Sets the ground speed.  This number is how many pixels it will move the ground to the left every frame.

var groundSpeed = 4




override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    //Misc setup tasks.

    //Sets the background colour when the view loads.        

    backgroundColor = (UIColor.blackColor())




    //Ground related tasks.

    //Positions the Ground image hard left in the X axis.

    self.movingGround.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)

    //Positions the Ground image at the bottom of the screen relative to half the height of the image.

    self.movingGround.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + (self.movingGround.size.height / 2))

    //Creates an instance of the Ground image that follows the parameters set in the lines above when the view loads.

    self.addChild(self.movingGround)

    //Sets the starting position for the ground image in the x before it start to move.

    self.originalMovingGroundPositionX = self.movingGround.position.x

    //Sets the maximum ground size minus the witdth of the screen to create the loop point in the image.

    self.MaxGroundX = self.movingGround.size.width - self.frame.size.width

    //This multiplies the size of the ground by itself and makes the max ground size a negative number as the image is moving towards the left in x which is negative.

    self.MaxGroundX *= -1





    //Hero related tasks.

    spriteArray.append(textureAtlas.textureNamed("Run1"));
    spriteArray.append(textureAtlas.textureNamed("Run2"));
    spriteArray.append(textureAtlas.textureNamed("Run3"));
    spriteArray.append(textureAtlas.textureNamed("Run2"));

    Hero = SKSpriteNode(texture:spriteArray[0]);

    self.HeroBaseLine = self.movingGround.position.y + (self.movingGround.size.height / 2) + 25

    //Sets where the character will appear exactly.

    self.Hero.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 50, self.HeroBaseLine)

    //Scales the image to an appropriate size.

    self.Hero.xScale = 0.15
    self.Hero.yScale = 0.15

    //Adds an instance of Hero to the screen.

    addChild(self.Hero);




    //Added this here as it didn't appear to work in the place recommended.

    jumpArray.append(jumpAtlas.textureNamed("Jump"));




    //I added this so that he runs when the view loads.

    if self.onGround {
        run()
    }
```

}

```
    //Animation function to make him run.  Here we can affect the frames and x, y movement, etc.

    func run() {
        let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(self.spriteArray, timePerFrame: 0.15);
        //Although currently set to 0, the above line controls the displacement of the character in the x and y axis if required.
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0), duration: 0.0);
        let group = SKAction.group([animateAction,moveAction]);
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(group);
        self.Hero.runAction(repeatAction);
    }




    //Animation function to make him jump.

    func jump() {

        self.velocityY = -18
        self.onGround = false

        let jumpAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(jumpArray, timePerFrame: 0.15)
        self.Hero.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(jumpAnimation))
    }




override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    //This block specifies what happens when the screen is touched.

    if self.onGround {
        jump()
    }
}




override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    //This block prevents Hero from jumping whilst already jumping.

    if self.velocityY < -9.0 {
        self.velocityY = -9.0
    }
}




override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */


    //This is how the ground is positioned at the beginning of each update (each frame refresh)

    if self.movingGround.position.x <= MaxGroundX {
        self.movingGround.position.x = self.originalMovingGroundPositionX
    }


    //This is how the ground is moved relative to the ground speed variable set at the top.  The number in the variable is how many pixels the frame is being moved each frame refresh.

    movingGround.position.x -= CGFloat (self.groundSpeed)


    //This is the code for making Hero jump in accordance to the velocity and gravity specified at the top of the class in realation to the base line and run when he hits the ground.

    if self.Hero.position.y < self.HeroBaseLine {
        self.Hero.position.y = self.HeroBaseLine
        velocityY = 0.0
        if self.onGround == false {
            self.onGround = true

            run()
    }

}
```

}

}

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's more conventional to write the comment right **before** the code.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed this too.

Comment: I will take a look later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have already made your sprite run, to jump is not a hard thing. Just replace the texture of run animation with the texture of jump animation in proper place.

Firstly, I wrap the code of run animation for reuse later.

```
func run() {
    let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(self.spriteArray, timePerFrame: 0.15);
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0), duration: 0.0);
    let group = SKAction.group([animateAction,moveAction]);
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(group);
    self.Hero.runAction(repeatAction);
}
```

Next step is for texture atlas of `Jump`. For demo, I just add one frame animation for jumping. Add these line after you create `textureAtlas` and `spriteArray` for `Run`.

```
var jumpArray = Array<SKTexture>()
let jumpAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named:"JumpImages.atlas")
jumpArray.append(jumpAtlas.textureNamed("Jump"))
```

After you write function `jump()`, you can call it in `touchesBegan`.

```
func jump() {
    self.velocityY = -18
    self.onGround = false
    println("jump over ground")

    let jumpAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(jumpArray, timePerFrame: 0.15)
    self.Hero.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(jumpAnimation))
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if self.onGround {
        jump()
    }
}
```

Last but not least, resume running animation after back to the ground in `update`.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    ...

    if self.Hero.position.y < self.HeroBaseLine {
        self.Hero.position.y = self.HeroBaseLine
        velocityY = 0.0
        if self.onGround == false {
            self.onGround = true
            println("on the ground")

            run()
        }
    }
}
```

Now you should get the result below. If you have any problem with the code, just let me know.

[image]

Comment: @Fiducial13 You missed two lines in `update` method in your edited code. They are `self.velocityY += self.gravity` and `self.Hero.position.y -= velocityY` which make the sprite jump.